# Script aborts when I try to build a very large list

Tags: performance-tuning, scripting

I am running the code below

```
f[N_, K_, snr_] := 
  Block[{H},
    H =
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], {N, K}] + 
        i RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], {N, K}];
    Return[
      {H[[All, 1]]}.
      Inverse[
        H[[All, 2 ;; K - 1]].
          ConjugateTranspose[H[[All, 2 ;; K - 1]]] + IdentityMatrix[N]/snr].
      ConjugateTranspose[{H[[All, 1]]}]]];
```

when I use

```
Table[Re[f[8, 4, 1]], {i, 1,90000}];
```

there is no problem for getting a Table of 90000 elements but for 100000 or more Table elements is not working.

```
Table[Re[f[8, 4, 1]], {i, 1,100000}];
```

The script stops and I have to compile again the function.

Besides, when I run the program in other computer works fine even for a Table of 100000 or more elements.

How to solve this problem in my computer?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange! I don't see any use of `Compile` in your posted code, is this correct? Do you get any messages when you try to run your code with a problem number of elements? Do you think you could be running out of memory?

Comment: Hi, thank you, for compile I mean that in order to have the function avaible I compile the function using Shift+Enter.  Maybe I could be running out of memory but there is no error message.

Comment: OK, that's typically not called "compiling" in Wolfram Language, and the [compile] question tag has specific semantics related to the function `Compile`. I'll remove that tag (not your fault, there are an awful lot of name clashes in Wolfram Language ). Can you clarify what happens when you say "the script stops"? I don't have any issues running that code for a million iterations and it doesn't seem memory-bounded (though it does appear CPU-bounded)

Comment: Ok. I mean for script stops that when I press Shift+Enter to obtain the Table with 100000 elements there is no result and the script looks like a recently openned script. Then it is necessary press Shift+Enter in order to have the function available again.

Comment: Sounds like the Kernel is crashing - but just to check, you know that having a semicolon at the end of your line will cause no output, right?

Comment: Yes, I know. I just updated to Wolfram 12.0.0 and the problem was solved. Thank you for your help. Maybe was the Kernel.

Comment: That's great; consider answering this question with that information.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by `I I` in the definition of `H`? All the values in the table are real valued. I'm assuming this is a typo?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. I have corrected using i to represent imaginary because the table is complex valued.